# Retrieve the request data from URI in Webview Windows 8.1

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-8.1, uwp-xaml

I'm developing a Windows phone 8.1 app and there's this scenario where I should open the webview for the user to enter the card details. Once the card details are entered and processed, the payment API will send the transaction details back as a POST request to the webview. I'm not able to get the POST data, tried so many methods.

How do I get the post data returned back from the server? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try using WebAuthenticationBrocker with WebAuthenticationOptions.useHttpPost option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this, actually the Server POST request had all the arguments in the Querystring itself

Handled the Navigation_Completed event of the webview, the args URI will have all the details required

Comment: In UWP this doesn't work. The query is empty. But I found a solution... err... more looks like workaround. but still something.. will post as answer here..

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to webpage code then you can use [WebBrowser.ScriptNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for transfering data from webpage to WP

Comment: No, I dont have access to the webpage, guess Im out of ideas

Comment: You can make POST request from WP application. May be getting POST result is like stealing data and by this way is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for UWP.**

**Important Note**: I have html document locally in localcache folder. I open it in webview using `ms-appdata://` scheme.

**Story of infinite troubles** (may be it some you some time):

If I sent the POST request, I got nothing. I get `WebView_NavigationStarting` event, but the Uri only was transferred. No POST data.

I try to debug using `alert`. Just to realize that `alert` doesn't work in `WebView`.

I found the fix that makes `alert` works using `ScriptNotify` events. Just to realize that `ScriptNotify` doesn't work with `ms-appdata://` scheme. So the fix didn't work as well.

I learned how debug in VS by going to Project settings / Debug / Debugger type / Application process and select "Script". Then I realized that I can't put breakpoints in script in Visual Studio. And then I found a little hack -- put the word "debugger;" in your javascript code and VS will stop there. And you can debug using F10/F11. Oh, yeah, baby!

Then I finally gave up and changed it to GET request. Just to realize that it only works until form data exceed ~2K. After that nothing. `NavigationStarting` never fired, just nothing happens.

---

Finally, here the **solution**:

```
    private async void WebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        string result = await this.WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "$('form').serialize()" });
    }
```

Not really elegant, but **it works**!!! And I was able to transfer 20K+ this way. This is exactly what I needed.