# C# UWP WebView NavigationStarting - Get Request Post data

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I'm wondering if I can get POST data of the `WebView` request in UWP.

I'm using `WebView_NavigationStarting` event to get information about URI, but I have custom page which sent some information back to the app inside the POST request. Ideally I want to do this:

```
    private void WebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        Stream receiveStream = args.Request.InputStream;
    }
```

But `args` doesn't have `Request`, only `Uri`. I was able to do this trick in iOS and Android (iOS, for example, pass the whole request to the similar event so why it's possible). Is there way to do so in UWP C# app ?

Comment: Did you want to achieve something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975434/retrieve-the-request-data-from-uri-in-webview-windows-8-1)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the request data from URI in Webview Windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975434/retrieve-the-request-data-from-uri-in-webview-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try listen to WebResourceRequested, the args contains both request and response object. It should be in args.request.Content. But so far I cannot access those content too.

```
private void WebView_WebResourceRequested(WebView sender, WebViewWebResourceRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.request.Method.Method == "POST")
    {
        HttpStreamContent content = (HttpStreamContent) args.request.Content;
        var contentBuffer = content.ReadAsBufferAsync().GetResults();
        byte[] buffer = contentBuffer.ToArray();
    }                    
}
```